# Loading external txt file into a DIV

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/9BCrs/2/

With respect to the above fiddle how could I use different links in block 1 to load up an external file (txt, HTML) in block 2 before it slides into view? I know that JQuery.load() will be part of the process

```
$(".block2").load("helloworld.txt");
```

Comment: I updated the Fiddle with that line of code so the first thing it does is load up. However, how do I stop it sliding before it loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - Provide your animate as a complete callback to the .load() function.

```
$(function() {
    $(".link1").click(function() {
        $.load("url/to/load/from", function() {
            //Insert contents of file wherever
            $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 200);
            $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
        });
    });

    $(".link2").click(function() {
        $.load("url/to/load/from", function() {
            //Insert contents of file wherever
            $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 450 }, 200);
            $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 25 }, 200);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I had to add (".block2") in front of .load but whereas the first one does animate fine, when I click the second link to load the second file the load occurs but it doesn't animate.